# Animation using transition manager is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I have been trying to change anchor gravity of fab (using co-ordinator layout parameters), but its happening abruptly instead of showing animation.

Here is the code which is I am using.

```
 fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()

        val anim = ChangeBounds()
        anim.pathMotion = ArcMotion()
        anim.duration = 200
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(
            container,
            anim
        )

        val params =  fab.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        if(!revealed){
            params.anchorGravity = Gravity.START
        }else{
            params.anchorGravity = Gravity.END
        }
        fab.layoutParams = params
        revealed = !revealed
    }
```

If I try changing margins of parameters, animation does happen but not with gravity, help is appreciated!

Comment: are you getting the error because of anim ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, it's just that animation is not happening. Fab is just changing the location without animation.